# Using UML to Understand Code

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I'm new to UML and I've managed to convert the source into class diagrams which shows every class in a box. but that doesn't seem like enough for me to understand how the functions and objects are connected.
Is that all what a programmer needs or what more can be done to better understand the information flow of their project? I'm currently working in 'Enterprise Architect'.

Comment: Do you mean you are using "Sparx Enterprise Architect"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class model (and class diagrams) only show the static structure of your code. They show nothing about interactions over time. You will want one of the behavior diagrams for that - a Sequence diagram, Activity diagram, or maybe even a State diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect the classes, if a class depends on another one, the link between them needs to be put in.

Connectors are not just for inheritance, they also describe objects used by the class or held within them.

Here's a [quicky tutorial](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~drobot/cs146/UMLDiagrams.htm).